# Json parsing using JavaScript showing blank page

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to get some data from a public API for a test project. But it is showing blank page when I'm using below code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x',
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].userId + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].title + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].body + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error `$.getJSON(http://api...'` Notice that you do not open the string. I'd go out and look for a tutorial on using javascript debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two reason why you see blank page,

1. *As mentioned in above comment* -- A missing single quote in `$.getJSON` URL, see you browser console for the errors before posting question in SO

   ```
    $.getJSON('http://api....', function(json){...})
   ```
2. You are appending all data to `<table>` tag but `<table>` tag is not there in your markup. Add a `<table>` tag, so that jQuery can append your data. Or dynamically create `<table>` element inside your ajax call.

Here's your modified code,

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <table></table>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x',
    function (json) {
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].userId + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].title + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].body + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code:
1. You have a syntax error in getJSON function.
2. Table element is not defined in your html.
3. The object you are getting back is an array of 'Trains'. So you would need to get trains by `json["Trains"]`

Here is your modified code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
</table>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/A10,A11?api_key=hadtcpbh3w5xjbtyqrzgm88x",
    function (json) {
      var trains = json["Trains"];
        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + trains[i].Car + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + trains[i].Destination + "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```